# Dialog-flow API integration in native android App

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I made a demo app for voice/text message using Dialog-flow API. I integrated that agent with Google action. Now I want to use this Dialog-flow agent/API in native android app. All are working fine as i test it on Google Action simulator and native android app.But not able to see google suggestion chips in native app, How i can solve this ?
Please help.

Comment: Please, show the code, that you think is wrong.

Comment: @sr9yar i am just following the dialog flow docs for integration AI. when i chat with agent, agent reply only standard messages. i want to show the suggestion chips also. Chips are working in Google Action simulator but not in my native app